# The meaning of "when disaster seemed positive" in Fahrenheit 451

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

The full paragraph:

> He hung up his black-beetle-coloured helmet and shined it, he hung his flameproof
> jacket neatly; he showered luxuriously, and then, whistling, hands in pockets, walked
> across the upper floor of the fire station and fell down the hole. At the last moment,
> ***when disaster seemed positive***, he pulled his hands from his pockets and broke his fall
> by grasping the golden pole. He slid to a squeaking halt, the heels one inch from the
> concrete floor downstairs.

(emphasis mine)

What does it exactly mean that "disaster seemed positive"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, **positive** means **certain**. Please see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/positive)

> **positive**
> <sub>ADJECTIVE</sub>
>
> **3** With no possibility of doubt; definite.

The subject accidentally fell through the hole used by firemen to get to ground level quickly. Before he hit the concrete floor, though, he was able to grasp the pole that the firemen slide down, and break his fall.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. However, I understood that that's what is meant by positive. The meaning of the phrase in its context is just not clear to me... What disaster seemed positive?

Comment: Falling directly on to the concrete floor.